# i need Step-by-Step Implementation for Simple CPUMAP Program in c

Tags: ebpf, bpf, xdp-bpf, libbpf, xdp-pdf

Hello Stack Overflow community,

I'm working on implementing a CPUMAP program in C and seeking guidance on the step-by-step process. My objective is to create a basic CPUMAP program to handle incoming packets efficiently.

I'm using C and the libbpf library to create a CPUMAP program for packet handling.

How do I initialize the CPUMAP structure properly?
What steps are involved in attaching the CPUMAP to a specific network interface?

How should incoming packets be handled within the CPUMAP program?

i want to forward all packets to the cpu1 of my cpu cores

```
#include <linux/bpf.h>
#include <bpf/bpf_helpers.h>

#define IFINDEX_LO      1

struct {
        __uint(type, BPF_MAP_TYPE_CPUMAP);
        __uint(key_size, sizeof(__u32));
        __uint(value_size, sizeof(struct bpf_cpumap_val));
        __uint(max_entries, 4);
} cpu_map SEC(".maps");

SEC("xdp")
int xdp_redir_prog(struct xdp_md *ctx)
{
        return bpf_redirect_map(&cpu_map, 1, 0);
}
```

the above is my xdp program which transfer all the incoming packets to the cpu 1 but it does not working please  help me to work on it